# Get Address Details after i select address in search box in leaflet js

Tags: leaflet, gis, openstreetmap

I am using leaflet for the first time as I am using open street map in place for Google.

In google autocomplete we use to get address's Suburb via

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

Can anyone help me in **leafletJs** to get address details.

Thanks Much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [leaflet latlng to name of location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909266/leaflet-latlng-to-name-of-location)

Answer (score 7):

For autocomplete address in leaflet JS you can use its plugin. Here Code uses the ESRI geoserach plugin.

you can refer this [link](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/geocoding-control.html) for more detail.

**DEMO**

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.91, -96.63], 4);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(map);

var results = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

searchControl.on('results', function(data) {
  results.clearLayers();
  for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Load Leaflet from CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>


<!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.1.4/dist/esri-leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-m+BZ3OSlzGdYLqUBZt3u6eA0sH+Txdmq7cqA1u8/B2aTXviGMMLOfrKyiIW7181jbzZAY0u+3jWoiL61iLcTKQ==" crossorigin=""></script>


<!-- Load Esri Leaflet Geocoder from CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.2.9/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css" integrity="sha512-v5YmWLm8KqAAmg5808pETiccEohtt8rPVMGQ1jA6jqkWVydV5Cuz3nJ9fQ7ittSxvuqsvI9RSGfVoKPaAJZ/AQ==" crossorigin="">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.2.9/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js" integrity="sha512-QXchymy6PyEfYFQeOUuoz5pH5q9ng0eewZN8Sv0wvxq3ZhujTGF4eS/ySpnl6YfTQRWmA2Nn3Bezi9xuF8yNiw==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the geocoding control to search for addresses and center the map.

```js
  var map = L.map('map').setView([-28.4792625, 24.6727135], 4);

  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(map);

  var results = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

  searchControl.on('results', function (data) {
    results.clearLayers();
    for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
    }
  });
```

```css
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Geocoding Control</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />

  <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
  crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
  crossorigin=""></script>


  <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.4.1/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-xY2smLIHKirD03vHKDJ2u4pqeHA7OQZZ27EjtqmuhDguxiUvdsOuXMwkg16PQrm9cgTmXtoxA6kwr8KBy3cdcw=="
  crossorigin=""></script>

  <!-- Load Esri Leaflet Geocoder from CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.3.3/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css"
    integrity="sha512-IM3Hs+feyi40yZhDH6kV8vQMg4Fh20s9OzInIIAc4nx7aMYMfo+IenRUekoYsHZqGkREUgx0VvlEsgm7nCDW9g=="
    crossorigin="">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.3.3/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js"
    integrity="sha512-HrFUyCEtIpxZloTgEKKMq4RFYhxjJkCiF5sDxuAokklOeZ68U2NPfh4MFtyIVWlsKtVbK5GD2/JzFyAfvT5ejA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/geocoding-control.html